NHibernate.dll 5.5.0.0 version issue, the error occurs when calling query.List() where “query” is an NHibernate interface
NHibernate.dll 5.5.0.0 version is working fine with small set of data  in production but For huge records, Query is not giving result and It’s giving timeout error at query.List() in code.
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(Queries.SelectAllObjectsOfAType);
                query.SetString("ObjectType", t.ToString());

                 System.Collections.IList list = query.List();

In this case, the error occurs when calling query.List() where “query” is an NHibernate interface. This could indicate that the operation being performed by NHibernate is taking a long time leading to the deadlock situation.
Error Description:
Message=Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' : 'The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0xd89ba8 to COM context 0xd89af0 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.'
Please help to resolve this performance issue of
NHibernate.dll 5.5.0.0 version  issue,  while with same data old Nhibernate.dll is working fine. I updated NHibernate.dll 5.5.0.0 due to update Log4net as 2.x to resolve vulnerability issue of old Log4net 1.x version.We can not use old Nhubernate dll version with latest log4net version.
